# ruby array take with parameters?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have array like this

month_string = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]

I want to take from may to sep.

take will work with single param.anyother  simple ways to do this.

output need to be:
 ["May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep"]

Comment: `month_string[4..8]` or am I missing the point?  Suggest you look here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html

Comment: And what's your input? Indices, month names? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

```
month_string[ month_string.index( "May" )..month_string.index( "Sep" ) ]
```

You can also make a function.

```
def month_set( months, a, b )
    months[ months.index(a)..months.index(b) ]
end

month_set( month_string, "May", "Sep")
```

or even include it in the function

```
def month_set( a, b )
    months = [
        "Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun",
        "Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"
    ]

    months[ months.index(a)..months.index(b) ]
end

month_set( "May", "Sep" )
```

Comment: `month_string[ month_string.index( "May" )..month_string.index( "Sep" ) ]` perfect.. Rest I am not getting,,

Comment: Fixed it.  I left out the index function.  Sorry about that oversight.